# Pass array as argument list to function

Tags: php, arrays, args

Google won't help me; I want to pass an array as an argument list to a function.

I can't edit the function itself, so I can't pass an array. 
It expects this:

```
function doSomething($arg1, $arg2, [$arg3...]) {
    //code...
}
```

And I have this:

```
$args = array('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'...);
```

How can I pass them anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

Use like:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3);
call_user_func_array("myfunc", $array);

function myfunc($a, $b, $c) {
    var_dump($a, $b, $c); // 1 2 3
}
```

---

```
$array = array(2, 3);
$first = 1;
call_user_func_array("myfunc", array_merge(arary($first), $array));

function myfunc($a, $b, $c) {
    var_dump($a, $b, $c); // 1 2 3
}
```

---

In case of an object instance your callback should look like:

```
array($obj, "someFunc")
```

so:

```
call_user_func_array(array($obj, "someFunc"), $array);
```

Comment: But how can I do this with the first arg not being in the array?

Comment: What do you mean? You can always do some `array_merge` magic to get the arguments you want.

Comment: Hmm, got it - but...
"call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '' not found or invalid function name"

$obj->doSomething not working

Comment: See my updated answer. Callbacks on objects are slightly different.